# Bluetooth broken after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: drivers, upgrade, kernel, 20.04, bluetooth

I just upgraded my computer from Ubuntu 19.10 to to Ubuntu 20.04, I haven't had any issues **except for Bluetooth not working.** This is what Bluetooth settings looks like:

[image]

So, I checked `lsmod`, `lspci`, and `lsusb` - nothing Bluetooth-related in any of them. In fact, it looks like **my drivers aren't even being loaded as a kernel module!** I have no idea why though.

`systemctl status bluetooth` yields the phrase "Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped" and I can't manually start it either. I *can* get bluetoothd to start by running `sudo modprobe btusb` or `sudo modprobe bluetooth` but then Bluetooth is still broken and all `bluetoothctl` commands just say "No default controller available"

Any help is greatly  appreciated, I have no idea how to even start debugging this. If it helps, my motherboard is an ASUS Z370-E.

**EDIT 1, output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb`:**

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [1043:8746]
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_pci
    Kernel modules: rtwpci
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0b05:1872 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. AURA LED Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c33a Logitech, Inc. G413 Gaming Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: You are correct. The BT disappeared from `lsusb`.